# how perforce submit atomic operation actually work

Tags: submit, perforce, atomic, rollback

perforce submit is atomic.

that means if the change list contains 3 files to be checked in, 
and the the operation successfully checked in the first 2 files, but then something when wrong 
when operating on the 3rd file, it has the ability to rollback the operation of the first 2 files so that everything went back to its original state.

I'm awed and really impressed with that, and tried to search for how that actually works, but couldn't seem to find it.

will appreciate a lot if someone could help me understand technical details on how all this works at the background.

thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that Perforce uses a database as its source of truth makes this very simple:

1. The depot files are locked (in the database, as if you'd run `p4 lock`).
2. The new revision contents are uploaded to the depot archive.
3. The database tables are locked for the final set of checks that everything is okay.
4. The new revision records are written into the database and all the locks are released.

If the submit fails somewhere in part 2, nothing needs to be rolled back, because the new revision contents don't overwrite anything, and they aren't visible as part of the file history until step 4.  (An unfortunate side effect of this is that Perforce can actually "leak" disk space on a failed submit, but this is generally pretty minor compared to the expected normal increase in disk usage over time.)

If you'd like to be able to watch this happen in real time, tailing the journal (`P4JOURNAL`) will show you the database writes as they happen, and tailing the log (`P4LOG`) will show you the individual phases of the submit operation from when the user initiates the operation to when the change is fully committed.

Comment: That is really helpful, @Sam. Thanks.

Comment: Good question and answer! This cleared my understanding of submit as well. What happens if I cannot unlock my files after they are globally locked? This is a problem I'm facing and I can't checkout anything else from my workspace.

Comment: You should always be able to unlock files that are locked by you.